# Accessing nested data in spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a collection of nested case classes. I've got a job that generates a dataset using these case classes, and writes the output to parquet.

I was pretty annoyed to discover that I have to manually do a load of faffing around to load and convert this data back to case classes to work with it in subsequent jobs. Anyway, that's what I'm now trying to do.

My case classes are like:

```
case class Person(userId: String, tech: Option[Tech])
case class Tech(browsers: Seq[Browser], platforms: Seq[Platform])
case class Browser(family: String, version: Int)
```

So I'm loading my parquet data. I can get the `tech` data as a `Row` with:

```
val df = sqlContext.load("part-r-00716.gz.parquet")
val x = df.head
val tech = x.getStruct(x.fieldIndex("tech"))
```

But now I can't find how to actually iterate over the browsers. If I try `val browsers = tech.getStruct(tech.fieldIndex("browsers"))` I get an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.Row
```

How can I iterate over my nested browser data using spark 1.5.2?

**Update**
In fact, my case classes contain optional values, so `Browser` actually is:

```
case class Browser(family: String,
               major: Option[String] = None, 
               minor: Option[String] = None,
               patch: Option[String] = None, 
               language: String,
               timesSeen: Long = 1,
               firstSeenAt: Long,
               lastSeenAt: Long)
```

I also have similar for `Os`:

```
case class Os(family: String,
          major: Option[String] = None,
          minor: Option[String] = None,
          patch: Option[String] = None,
          patchMinor: Option[String],
          override val timesSeen: Long = 1,
          override val firstSeenAt: Long,
          override val lastSeenAt: Long)
```

And so `Tech` is really:

```
case class Technographic(browsers: Seq[Browser], 
                     devices: Seq[Device],
                     oss: Seq[Os])
```

Now, given the fact that some values are optional, I need a solution that will allow me to reconstruct my case classes correctly. The current solution doesn't support `None` values, so for example given the input data:

```
Tech(browsers=Seq(
    Browser(family=Some("IE"), major=Some(7), language=Some("en"), timesSeen=3),
    Browser(family=None, major=None, language=Some("en-us"), timesSeen=1),
    Browser(family=Some("Firefox), major=None, language=None, timesSeen=1)
  )
)
```

I need it to load the data as follows:

```
family=IE, major=7, language=en, timesSeen=3,
family=None, major=None, language=en-us, timesSeen=1,
family=Firefox, major=None, language=None, timesSeen=1
```

Because the current solution doesn't support `None` values, it in fact has an arbitrary number of values per list item, i.e.:

```
browsers.family = ["IE", "Firefox"]
browsers.major = [7]
browsers.language = ["en", "en-us"]
timesSeen = [3, 1, 1]
```

As you can see, there's no way of converting the final data (returned by spark) into the case classes that generated it.

How can I work around this insanity?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some examples

```scala
// Select two columns
df.select("userId", "tech.browsers").show()

// Select the nested values only
df.select("tech.browsers").show(truncate = false)
+-------------------------+
|browsers                 |
+-------------------------+
|[[Firefox,4], [Chrome,2]]|
|[[Firefox,4], [Chrome,2]]|
|[[IE,25]]                |
|[]                       |
|null                     |
+-------------------------+

// Extract the family (nested value)
// This way you can iterate over the persons, and get their browsers
// Family values are nested
df.select("tech.browsers.family").show()
+-----------------+
|           family|
+-----------------+
|[Firefox, Chrome]|
|[Firefox, Chrome]|
|             [IE]|
|               []|
|             null|
+-----------------+

// Normalize the family: One row for each family
// Then you can iterate over all families
// Family values are un-nested, empty values/null/None are handled by explode()
df.select(explode(col("tech.browsers.family")).alias("family")).show()
+-------+
| family|
+-------+
|Firefox|
| Chrome|
|Firefox|
| Chrome|
|     IE|
+-------+
```

Based on the last example:

```scala
val families = df.select(explode(col("tech.browsers.family")))
  .map(r => r.getString(0)).distinct().collect().toList
println(families)
```

gives the unique list of browers in a "normal" local Scala list:

> List(IE, Firefox, Chrome)

Comment: How can I alias columns? I have multiple other tech case classes with attributes called `family`, and if I then call `.getList(x.fieldIndex("family"))` it only gives me the last one. Also, browsers actually has `Option`s for `family` and `version`. Is there any guarantee here that if a value is `None` data will align if I zip it together? Also what does `explode` do? I read the API but it was no help.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The last example uses an alias. All examples iterate over the complete data frame, so these do not return only the last one. As for the zip, provide the input, and the expected result. explode() unnests/normalizes nested values by transforming these into new rows.

Comment: OK so explode makes it work, but I can't see how to select a whole list of columns - I only seem to be able to select a single one with `explode`. How can I select all columns, exploding the array elements?

Comment: explode() won't work with multiple columns: It only unnests one column. The first version of the question was about "iterate over browsers" (= skip person and tech), now it has changed to "convert all into case classes". Please roll back the question, as this answer does not match the question any longer. Then open another question dealing with "convert back to case classes".

Comment: Of course, because I expected a different solution. Anyway I've created http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071174/how-to-convert-parquet-data-to-case-classes-with-spark