# How to convert parquet data to case classes with spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've have a load of case classes which I've used in spark to save data as parquet, e.g.:

```
case class Person(userId: String,
              technographic: Option[Technographic] = None,
              geographic: Option[Geographic] = None)

case class Technographic(browsers: Seq[Browser], 
                     devices: Seq[Device],
                     oss: Seq[Os])

case class Browser(family: String,
               major: Option[String] = None, 
               language: String

...
```

How can I convert the data on disk back to these case classes?

I need to be able to select multiple columns and explode them so that the for each list (e.g. `browsers`) all of the sub lists have the same lengths.

E.g. Given this original data:

```
Person(userId="1234",
  technographic=Some(Technographic(browsers=Seq(
    Browser(family=Some("IE"), major=Some(7), language=Some("en")),
    Browser(family=None, major=None, language=Some("en-us")),
    Browser(family=Some("Firefox), major=None, language=None)
  )),
  geographic=Some(Geographic(...))
)
```

I need, e.g. for the browser data to be as follows (as well as being able to select all columns):

```
family=IE, major=7, language=en
family=None, major=None, language=en-us
family=Firefox, major=None, language=None
```

which I could get if spark could `explode` each list item. Currently it will just do something like (and anyway `explode` won't work with multiple columns):

```
browsers.family = ["IE", "Firefox"]
browsers.major = [7]
browsers.language = ["en", "en-us"]
```

So how how can I reconstruct a user's record (the entire set of case classes that produced a row of data) from all this nested optional data using spark 1.5.2?

One possible approach is:

```
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(inputPath)
df.registerTempTable("person")
val fields = df.select("desc person")
df.select("select * from person").map { x => 
  ... // somehow zip `fields` with the values so that I can 
      // access values by column name instead of index 
      // (which is brittle), but how?
}
```

Comment: can you please post your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert spark SchemaRDD into RDD of my case class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26181353/how-to-convert-spark-schemardd-into-rdd-of-my-case-class)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```
case class Browser(family: String,
                   major: Option[Int] = None,
                   language: String)

case class Tech(browsers: Seq[Browser],
                devices: Seq[String],
                oss: Seq[String])


case class Person(userId: String,
                  tech: Option[Tech] = None,
                  geographic: Option[String] = None)
```

and some convenience types/functions for `org.apache.spark.sql.Row`

```
type A[E] = collection.mutable.WrappedArray[E]

implicit class RichRow(val r: Row) {
  def getOpt[T](n: String): Option[T] = {
    if (isNullAt(n)) {
      None
    } else {
      Some(r.getAs[T](n))
    }
  }

  def getStringOpt(n: String) = getOpt[String](n)
  def getString(n: String) = getStringOpt(n).get

  def getIntOpt(n: String) = getOpt[Int](n)
  def getInt(n: String) = r.getIntOpt(n).get

  def getArray[T](n: String) = r.getAs[A[T]](n)

  def getRow(n: String) = r.getAs[Row](n)
  def getRows(n: String) = r.getAs[A[Row]](n)

  def isNullAt(n: String) = r.isNullAt(r.fieldIndex(n))
}
```

then parsing can be organized in some functions:

```
def toBrowser(r: Row): Browser = {
  Browser(
    r.getString("family"),
    r.getIntOpt("major"),
    r.getString("language"))
}

def toBrowsers(rows: A[Row]): Seq[Browser] = {
  rows.map(toBrowser)
}

def toTech(r: Row): Tech = {
  Tech(
    toBrowsers(r.getRows("browsers")),
    r.getArray[String]("devices"),
    r.getArray[String]("oss"))
}

def toTechOpt(r: Row): Option[Tech] = {
  Option(r).map(toTech)
}

def toPerson(r: Row): Person = {
  Person(
    r.getString("userId"),
    toTechOpt(r.getRow("tech")),
    r.getStringOpt("geographic"))
}
```

so you can write

```
df.map(toPerson).collect().foreach(println)
```

---

- I have organized the parse functions into "stand-alone" methods. I'd normally put these either as `apply` into the companion object of the case class or as implicit values classes for `Row` as well. The reason for functions is that this is easier to paste into the `spark-shell`
- Each parse function handles plain columns and arrays directly, but delegates to another function when it encounters a collection (`Seq` and `Option` - these represent the next nesting level)
- The `implict class` should `extend AnyVal`, but again this cannot be pasted into the `spark-shell`

Comment: Thanks dude. I'm surprised this isn't better documented since loading data is a pretty critical thing to do and saving from case classes is so easy.

Comment: You're welcome. I was surprised as well (especially in the case of deeply nested values). I haven't found a macro based solution either.

Comment: @jbrown I have added `RichRow.getOpt[T]`: This version uses `isNullAt` and avoids `getAs`, because the latter uses `asInstanceOf`. In other words there is only an `asInstanceOf`, if it's really not null.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the accepted answer, it doesn't correctly deal with null values. You need to try to cast it to a string to find out whether it's null. However, that will only be successful if the value is null - if the value is non-null it will result in a casting exception.

Confused? Here's teh codez:

```
implicit class RichRow(val r: Row) extends AnyVal {

    def getBoolean(n: String) = r.getAs[Boolean](n)
    def getBooleanOpt(n: String) = Try(r.getString(n)) match {
      case Success(_) => None
      case _ => Option(r.getBoolean(n))
    }

    def getString(n: String) = r.getAs[String](n)
    def getStringOpt(n: String) = Option(r.getString(n))

    def getLong(n: String) = r.getAs[Long](n)
    def getLongOpt(n: String) = Try(r.getString(n)) match {
      case Success(_) => None
      case _ => Option(r.getLong(n))
    } 

    def getInt(n: String) = r.getAs[Int](n)
    def getIntOpt(n: String) = Try(r.getString(n)) match {
      case Success(_) => None
      case _ => Option(r.getInt(n))
    } 

    def getFloat(n: String) = r.getAs[Float](n)
    def getFloatOpt(n: String) = Try(r.getString(n)) match {
      case Success(_) => None
      case _ => Option(r.getFloat(n))
    }

    def getArray[T](n: String) = r.getAs[A[T]](n)

    def getRow(n: String) = r.getAs[Row](n)
    def getRows(n: String): A[Row] = r.getAs[A[Row]](n)
  }
}
```